# Angularjs, I can't get the node.js server file to run

Tags: node.js, angularjs, git-bash

I get an error window:

> Windows Script Host
>
> Script: ...angular\scripts\web-server.js
> Line: 1
> Char: 1
> Error: Invalid character
> Code: 800A03F6
> Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error

Any ideas? This is my first real foray into Git and node.js and angular, so forgive me in advance for silly questions :-D

Sorry for the lack of info, I've gotten so far as to install node.js and I'm trying to start the web-server.js, which should make this display the page at
`http://localhost:8000/app/index.html`

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult to determine what is really going on here, especially since we don't get to see ANY of the code that is doing this. Could you edit your question and add some?

Comment: @Nick added a lil bit, anything else I could add to help? I just want to get node.js running correctly I suppose...so I can get through the angularjs tutorial

Comment: @Nick ah hell, I just figured it out it, I was missing the 'node' in front of scripts\web-server.js  DERP!

Comment: Glad you got it working then!

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your path to the script.

Comment: a little late, hhhmm?